# MacOS Resolution of localhost

Tags: network, dns, resolution

Does anyone know the exact mechanism by which `localhost` is resolved to `127.0.0.1` on MacOS ***without*** an entry in `/etc/hosts`? Is it logic encoded in mDNSResponder itself or something similar, or more high level in a config file somewhere?

Further, how could I determine this myself?  For example, via system call tracing or similar?

Comment: What problem/issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's kind of a long story and I'm not sure relevant to the question.

Comment: It is always good to give a brief summary of a seemingly theoretical question as that will often give the people here a clue as to why you are asking and possibly a better chance of getting an applicable answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seem like this is, in fact, hardcoded in mDNSResponder.

```
╰─ grep -A5 -B5 "Register localhost" ./mDNSResponder-1096.40.7/mDNSMacOSX/mDNSMacOSX.c
        const domainname *const localHostName     = (const domainname *) "\x9" "localhost";
        const domainname *const broadcastHostName = (const domainname *) "\xd" "broadcasthost";
        const mDNSv4Addr        localHostV4       = { { 127, 0, 0, 1 } };
        mDNSv6Addr              localHostV6;
        // Register localhost 127.0.0.1 A record.
        RegisterLocalOnlyARecord(localHostName, &localHostV4);
        // Register broadcasthost 255.255.255.255 A record.
--
--
        // Register broadcasthost 255.255.255.255 A record.
        RegisterLocalOnlyARecord(broadcastHostName, &onesIPv4Addr);
        // Register localhost ::1 AAAA record.
        mDNSPlatformMemZero(&localHostV6, sizeof(localHostV6));
        localHostV6.b[15] = 1;
        RegisterLocalOnlyAAAARecord(localHostName, &localHostV6);
    }
```